# Github API v3 POST with PHP

Tags: php, github, github-api

I'm attempting to use the Github v3 API and posting JSON to update a profile (or some other call) and get the following response from Github;

```
Array
(
    [message] => Body should be a JSON Hash 
)
```

I have gone over the relevant page on the API Docs: http://developer.github.com/v3/users/

And this page: http://developer.github.com/v3/#http-verbs which covers POST/PATCH

Here is the code that I'm using

```
$data = array("bio" => "This is my bio" );
$data_string = json_encode($data); 

function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);  

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USERNAME:PASSWORD");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);   
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}

$result = json_decode(curl('https://api.github.com/user'),true);
```

I have also tried `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` as `'POST'` and `'PATCH'` but got the same error response for both.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for posting data to the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either `global $data_string` or pass the `$data_string` variable to `curl()` for reusability.

Example:

```
function curl($curl, $data)
{
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Wow... how did I over look that!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the header like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```